# Sql script to eliminate data duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a script which will get all values from 4 columns in 2 tables and insert each of distinct value to another table. (SQL Server 2012)

i.e.

```
table1
|column1|column2|column3| some other columns here|
|value  | value | value |                        |
|value1 | value | value3|                        |

table2
|column4|other columns|
|value  | some value  |
```

**1)** First question is: How to get distinct of all 4 columns from 2 tables in examples it will be column1, column2, column3 and column4? (foreach column i need to know name of table as well and ideally it would be if I could get column name as well)

**2)** and which approach should I use here? (cursor or simply temporary table and while statement or maybe something else)? All thing should be as fast as it can be for lets say milion+ rekords in each table

**Edit:**

There is no relation between this two tables.
Expected result: there should be only 3 values returnded: `value, value1 ,value3`

Comment: What is the expected output for the tables above?

Comment: How data from this tables relates each to other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This union will get distinct values across 4 columns...

```
select v = col1 from table1
union select col2 from table1
union select col3 from table1
union select col4 from table2
```

Comment: I'll try it in the morning :) But I gues it's exacly what i'm looking for :)